# What does "ask" mean in Haskell and what's the difference of it and "asks" function?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, reader-monad

I can't understand how to use the `ask` function, I know how to use the `asks` function, but I don't know if they're related.

I was reading the "What I wish I knew when learning Haskell" of Stephen and I found this example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State

type Stack = [Int]
type Output = [Int]
type Program = [Instr]

type VM a = ReaderT Program (WriterT Output (State Stack)) a

newtype Comp a = Comp { unComp :: VM a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, 
                MonadReader Program, MonadWriter Output, 
                  MonadState Stack)

data Instr = Push Int
            | Pop
            | Puts

evalInstr :: Instr -> Comp ()
evalInstr instr = case instr of
                    Pop -> modify tail
                    Push n -> modify (n:)
                    Puts -> do
                        tos <- gets head
                        tell [tos]

eval :: Comp ()
eval = do
    instr <- ask
    case instr of
      [] -> return ()
      (i:is) -> evalInstr i >> local (const is) eval

execVM :: Program -> Output
execVM = flip evalState [] . execWriterT . runReaderT (unComp eval)

program :: Program
program = [
        Push 42,
        Push 27,
        Puts,
        Pop,
        Puts,
        Pop
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print $ execVM program
```

So, my question is: from where the list was taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask` is `asks id`. While in...

```
do
    x <- asks f
    -- etc.
```

... `x` will be the result of applying `f` to the environment of your `MonadReader` computation, in...

```
do
    x <- ask
    -- etc.
```

... `x` will be the environment itself.